# Set the colorbar plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following code

```
library(plotly)

fig1 <- plot_ly(
    type = "heatmap",
    x = c(1,2,3,4),
    z = list(c(1,2,3,4), c(4,-3,-1,1)),
    coloraxis = 'coloraxis')
fig2 <- plot_ly(
    type = "heatmap",
    x = c(3,4,5,6),
    z = list(c(10,2,1,0), c(4,3,5,6)),
    coloraxis = 'coloraxis')
fig <- subplot(fig1, fig2)
fig <- fig %>% layout(coloraxis=list(colorscale='Jet'))

fig
```

which result in the following figure
[image: heatmap Figure]

But I would like to set the colorbal in the same scale as positive values. For example, from zero to 300 it is gradient red, but I would like to set the same from zero to -300 (gradient red) and not gradient blue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Are you trying to make the colors more along the lines of set by absolute value? You can't create a color scale of any colors. For example, you could replace `'jet'` with `list(list(0, 'blue'), list(.5, 'white'), list(1, 'blue'))`